# Node: Check for null value is not working

Tags: node.js

In the following function, I parse the request header and obtain the value of the currentUser. I log the value of currentUser and and get the following:

```
console.log('currentUser', currentUser)
currentUser null
```

But the following conditional statement of the currentUser does not evaluate to null and subsequent lines are executed:

```
if (!currentUser) {
    console.log('\n user not logged in');
    res.status(401).json('User not logged in');
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of null
at exports.authenticate (sandbox2\nghd09\backend\app\controllers\user.server.controller.js:47:40)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (sandbox2\nghd09\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Entire function:

```
exports.authenticate = function (req, res, next) {
    var headerExists = req.headers.authorization;
    console.log('authenticate called', headerExists)
    var currentUser = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    console.log('currentUser', currentUser)

    if (!currentUser) {
        console.log('\n user not logged in');
        res.status(401).json('User not logged in');
    }

    // if (currentUser) {
    var token = JSON.parse(currentUser).token;
    console.log('\ntoken', token)
    jwt.verify(token, config.sessionSecret, function (err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(401).json('Unauthorized');
        } else {
            req.user = decoded.username;
            req.password = decoded.password;
            next();
        }
    })
    // }
}
```

I have followed the recommendations of several Stackoverflow's answers but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `currentUser` is a result of `split`, it can be either a string or `undefined`. It can be logged as `null` only if it is `'null'` string. The confusion comes from the fact that `null` and `'null'` are indistinguishable when being output with `console.log`.

> But the following conditional statement of the currentUser does not evaluate to null

This is possible only if `currentUser` is `'null'` string (or any object that has custom `toString` method that returns `'null'` string).

If `currentUser` is `'null'`,  `JSON.parse(currentUser)` evaluates to `null`, this way `Cannot read property 'token' of null` error is possible.

> and subsequent lines are executed

`if (currentUser) {` is currently commented, so they will be executed regardless of `currentUser`.

The problem likely should be addressed by performing `JSON.parse` beforehand:

```
var currentUser = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
if (currentUser !== undefined) {
   currentUser = JSON.parse(currentUser);
}

if (!currentUser) {
    console.log('\n user not logged in');
    res.status(401).json('User not logged in');
}
```

The fact that there was null in authorization header is an another problem that possibly should be additionally addressed.

Comment: JSON.parse(currentUser) should never be reached if currentUser is null. Control should be returned to the client by the following statement: res.status(401).json('User not logged in');

Comment: But it is not `null`. It's `'null'`.

Comment: It will fail again if it's `'undefined'` string, for example. JSON.parse is a cleaner solution.

Comment: The current problem: this works: if (currentUser == 'null'). But I expect the following line to return control to the client: res.status(401).json('User not logged in'); It doesn't seem to be happening, I am still getting the parse token error which I believe should never be reached.

Comment: Do you still have `if (currentUser) {` commented? You should either uncomment it, or return from a function, or replace it with `else`. The solution I've proposed addresses it. Because both  `if (currentUser == 'null')` and `if (currentUser) {` are true conditions and won't work as intended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172415/discussion-between-koque-and-estus).

Comment: I don't use chats because they don't work well with offline. *Why is res.status(401).json('User not logged in'); not returning to the client?* can't say why, it's related to your app. But you should return from the function in order to not evaluate the rest of it. If you don't handle control flow with `if`, you should at least place `return` there.

Answer (score 0):

Within the null check

```
if (!currentUser) {
  console.log('\n user not logged in');
  res.status(401).json('User not logged in');
  //return next();   // should return next here to stop current function
}
```

Just print out log, but not terminating the execution. The codes below would still be executed.

Comment: When there is an error, I want to return processing to the client by doing this:  res.status(401).json('User not logged in'); next() would continue processing on the server which isn't the outcome I want.

Comment: In this case `res.status(401).send('User not logged in'); return;` will do the trick. The main point is stop execution in the null check
.